# In-line code stopping

Tags: python, loops

i've got an annoying bit of code that i want to have something happen to...

```
import time
global END
END = 0
def bacteria():
b = int(input("Bacteria number? "))
l = int(input("Limit? "))
i = (float(input("Increase by what % each time? ")))/100+1
h = 0
d = 0
w = 0
while b < l:
    b = b*i
    h = h+1
else:
    while h > 24:
        h = h-24
        d = d+1
    else:
        while d > 7:
            d = d-7
            w = w+1
print("The bacteria took " + str(w) + " weeks, " + str(d) + " days and " + str(h) + " hours.")
def runscript():
    ANSWER = 0
    ANSWER = input("Run what Program? ")
    if ANSWER == "bacteria":
        print(bacteria())
        ANSWER = 0
    if ANSWER == "jimmy":
        print(jimmy())
        ANSWER = 0
    if ANSWER == "STOP" or "stop":
        quit()
while True:
    print(runscript())
```

So, after the line "if ANSWER == "STOP" or "stop":" i want the script to end; but only if i have entered STOP or stop as the ANSWER, to stop the otherwise infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

Right now, your code is being interpreted like this:

```
if (ANSWER == "STOP") or ("stop"):
```

Furthermore, since non-empty strings evaluate to `True` in Python, this if-statement will *always* pass because `"stop"` will always evaluate to `True`.

To fix the problem, use [`in`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#in):

```
if ANSWER in ("STOP", "stop"):
```

or [`str.lower`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower)*:

```
if ANSWER.lower() == "stop":
```

---

*Note: As @gnibbler commented below, if you are on Python 3.x, you should use [`str.casefold`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) instead of `str.lower`. It is more unicode compatible.

Comment: In Python3, you can use `str.casefold` for better unicode compatibility

Comment: @gnibbler - Good point.  Let me mention that.

Answer (score 0):

In python the `or` [operator returns true if any of the two operands are non zero](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/logical_operators_example.htm).

In this case adding brackets helps clarify exactly what your current logic is:

```
if((ANSWER == "STOP") or ("stop")):
```

In python `if("stop")` will always return `True`. Because if this the entire condition is always true and `quite()` will always execute.

In order to fix this you can change your logic to:

```
if(ANSWER == "STOP") or (ANSWER == "stop"):
```

or

```
if ANSWER in ["STOP","stop"]:
```